# how to use bootstrap simulation, is this method correct?

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap

I just wanted to find out if my method is correct. 
the problem goes like this: I have 29 observations in a data set on which i plan to compute logistic regression involving 3 independent variables, but I know that this sample size is small so I decided to use bootstrap method  by resampling 50 observations about 1000 times. from my 29 observations to run the logistic regression. from this  i got 1000 coefficients, null deviance and residuals which i plan to use as the test statistics. my question goes thus: is this method ok especially to resample 50 observations instead of 29 observations 1000 times?

Answer (score 1):

Generating larger apparent sample sizes in this way is not OK. Bootstrapping multiple samples of the same size, with replacement, uses information already in the original data sample to estimate, for example, how well results from that sample might generalize to other samples of the same size from the underlying population. Bootstrapping can't, however, add additional information that isn't already in the original data sample.

For logistic regression, you are limited not just by the number of total observations but also by the number of cases in the smallest of the two classes. That can't be more than 14 in your case, which is barely enough to consider even a single independent variable unless you use a technique like ridge regression to avoid overfitting.

Comment: thanks but if I get my original samples up to 50 and bootstrap with the 50 samples will that be appropriate

Comment: Thanks but what if I get my original observations up to 50 and then use the bootstrap method as above will that be fine?

Comment: If you have 50 observations then bootstrapping multiple samples of 50 with replacement is correct. This will not, however, overcome the limitation placed by the number of cases in the lower-frequency category. For standard logistic regression there should be no fewer than about 15 cases in the lower-frequency category per independent variable, or else there is a risk of overfitting (which bootstrapping might  demonstrate, but not fix). For 3 independent variables you need about 45 cases in the lowest-frequency category, or you need to use a penalized method like ridge regression.